# Ember.js Binding value to JSon object

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to bind an input value to a JSon object but I can't find a way to make it work.

Here is a sample of my object.

```
Data = {
    value = "test"
};
```

and my App.FIXTURES

```
App.FIXTURES = [
    {
       title : "What is your age?",
       linkedTo : Data.value
    }
];
```

And my template:

```
 {{#each questions}}
     {{title}}
     {{input type="text" valueBinding=linkedTo}}
 {{/each}}
```

The binding works only in one way, it retrieve the value to display but when I try to access the `Data.value` field it never change.

Is it possible to do this? I tried several ways without success. Do I have to extend the `Ember.Textfield`? If yes, how would you implement this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [tavi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1028355/tavi), I came with an new idea of getting my problem solved.

I created a new custom view extending the `Ember.TextField`:

```
App.CustomTextField = Em.TextField.extend({
    keyUp:function(event){
        console.log(this.get('value'));
        //Watch input for Security code injection!!
        eval(linkedto + ' = this.get(\'value\')');
    }
});
```

So everytime I update the value it is fully synchronized between my textfield and json.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript strings are immutable.  You're essentially copying the value `"test"` to `linkedTo` not linking it up to `Data.value`

Comment: I figured this out when testing, but I'm trying to get a way to make this work :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if what [kingpin2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1257694/kingpin2k) is true I have a  suggestion in case you still want to achieve this kind of functionality. So try and use an object whose key to change instead of the actual string value.

What I mean is that instead on using the actual string to bind to, use instead an object and bind to a property. So instead of using `Data.value` string value directly you will use `Data.value` as an object with a key `actualValue` that will hold the string's value. Now ember can set up it's magic to bind to this property and change the value.

So when you want to get the `Data.value` string value you instead go for `Data.value.actualValue` which is bound to the `linkedTo.actualValue`

So your code would become:

```
var Data = {
  value: {
    actualValue: 'test'
  }
};

App.FIXTURES = [
  {key: 'red', linkedTo: Data.value}
];
```

In the template:

```
{{input type="text" valueBinding=linkedTo.actualValue}}
```

And where you will get the value:

```
el.innerHTML = Data.value.actualValue + '<br/>' + el.innerHTML;
```

Here is a demo of the things I tried to explain [emberjs jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wokij/3/edit)

Comment: Nice trick, but my JSon comes from API and I'm not able to reformat it the way i'd like.. :(